# How to write the APN Settings in Android 4.2 programmatically

Tags: android

I want to write the APN settings in android version 4.2 programmatically. Please share any way to do this. I need this to send the MMS programmatically without intent.

Please help me for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is not possible, unless you have the `WRITE_APN_SETTINGS` permission, which is only available to apps installed by rooted device users on the system partition, or as part of your own ROM mod.